# Show there must be an ordered basis $\beta$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that a linear function takes the form of a certain basis transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

**Prove:** Let $A$ be a $2$ x $2$ matrix such that $trace(A) = -6$ and $det(A) = 9$, but $A \neq -3I$. Show that there must be an ordered basis $\beta$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the linear transformation $f(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x}$ takes the form $$(f)^\beta_\beta = \left[\begin{array}{cc} -3 & 1 \\ 0 & -3 \\ \end{array} \right]$$
In the outline of my proof I use the following two, already established, theorems
 **Theorem 1:** Every $2$ x $2$ matrix $M$ satisfies $M^2 - trace(M)M + det(M)I = 0$.
**Threorem 2:** Let $V$ be a vector space and $f: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear function. If $\vec{u}$ is a vector in $V$ such that $f(\vec{u}) \neq 0$ but $f(f(\vec{u})) = 0$, then the list $\vec{u},f(\vec{u})$ is linearly independent.

The outline of my proof is as follows. By theorem 1, $A^2 + 6A + 9I = 0$. Let $\beta_1$ be a vector that satisfies theorem 2. Multiply both sides of the equation by $\beta_1$ and use algebra to obtain $A(A\beta_1 + 3\beta_1) = -3(A\beta_1 + 3\beta_1)$. Let $\beta_2 = A\beta_1 + 3\beta_1$. Note that since $\beta_1$ and $A\beta_1$ are linearly independent by theorem 2, $\beta_2$ and $\beta_1$ are linearly independent. Thus, we have $$A\beta_1 = -3\beta_1 + \beta_2$$ $$A\beta_2 = -3\beta_2$$ All that's left is to show that there exists $\beta_1$ that satisfies theorem 1. In other words, $A\beta_1 \neq 0$ but $A^2\beta_1 = 0$. However, if I multiply both sides of $A^2 +6A + 9I = 0$ by $\beta_1$, then this equation simplifies to $A\beta_1 = -\frac{3}{2}\beta_1$. This indicates that $A\beta_1$ and $\beta_1$ are linearly dependent, leading to a contradiction.

I am told that both of stated theorems are useful in this problem, so I must have made a mistake somewhere, I would like to know what this mistake was and how to complete the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\det A=9\neq0$, $\det A^2\neq0$ and therefore the only vector $v$ such that $A^2v=0$ is the null vector. So, you cannot apply theorem 2 directly to $A$. Apply it to $A+3\operatorname{Id}$ instead.